# Http Get- Gat an object from web api

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to get a list of objects from web api.
This is the server code:

```
public IQueryable<PersonViewModel> GetPeople()
{
    var People = from p in db.People
                select new PersonViewModel()
                {
                    Id = p.Id,
                    FirstName = p.FirstName,
                    LastName = p.LastName,
                    IdentityNo = p.IdentityNo,
                    DateOfBirth = p.DateOfBirth
                };

    return People;

}

[Route("api/Person/GetPersonById/{value?}")]
public IQueryable<PersonViewModel> GetPersonById(string value = "")
{
    if (value != null)
    {
        var a= GetPeople().Where(x => x.IdentityNo.StartsWith(value));
        return a;
    }
    else return GetPeople();

}
```

**Person Model:**

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public PersonViewModel()
    {

    }
    public PersonViewModel(Person p)
    {
        Id = p.Id;
        FirstName = p.FirstName;
        LastName= p.LastName;
        IdentityNo = p.IdentityNo;
        DateOfBirth = p.DateOfBirth;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string IdentityNo { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

Client side code:
This is model:

```
export class Person  {
    Id:string;
    FirstName :string;
    LastName:string;
    IdentityNo:string;
    DateOfBirth:Date;
}
```

I had a service which is containing a list of Person type,
and a function which trying to get the data from the server.

```
PersonIdList: Person[];

getPersonById(uri: string){
    this.http.get('http://localhost:58527/api/Person/GetPersonById/' + uri)
        .map((data: Response) => {
            return data.json() as Person[];
        }).toPromise().then(x => { this.PersonIdList = x; })
}
```

But I don't get any results in the list, when debugging PersonIdList is undefined.
The error message:

> ReferenceError: PersonIdList is not defined at eval (eval at
>   PersonService.getPersonById(webpack-internal:///./src/app/Shared/person.service.ts),
>   :1:1) at
>   PersonService.getPersonById(webpack-internal:///./src/app/Shared/person.service.ts:26:5)
>   at MainComponent.onSubmit
>   (webpack-internal:///./src/app/pages/main/main.component.ts:58:28) at
>   Object.eval [as handleEvent]
>   (ng:///AppModule/MainComponent.ngfactory.js:387:31)↵ at handleEvent
>   (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:13805:155)↵
>   at callWithDebugContext
>   (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:15314:42)↵
>   at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent]
>   (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:14901:12)↵
>   at dispatchEvent
>   (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:10220:25)↵
>   at eval
>   (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:10845:38)↵
>   at HTMLButtonElement.eval
>   (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/esm5/platform-browser.js:2680:53)

Comment: Is server responding with the correct JSON response? Can you post the entire service code as well?

Comment: What happens if you remove `return` from map? Looking at this example: https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/http/requests_as_promises.html they didn't use `return` there.

Answer (score 1):

it seems this is related to referencing,
can you try with persisting 'this' reference, like this **let _this = this;**

```
function getPersonById(uri) {
let _this = this;
this.http.get('http://localhost:58527/api/Person/GetPersonById/' + uri)
    .map(function (data) {
    return data.json();
}).toPromise().then(function (x) { _this.PersonIdList = x; });
```

}